# jquery json function not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This jquery function that sends a variable and retrieve data from a php file

```
function update(){  
    var nid = $("#identity").val(); 
    //alert(nid);
    $.getJSON('../js_backend/getComment.php', {n:nid},function(data){
        $("#comment_view_spot").empty();    
        $.each(data.result, function(){
            $("#comment_view_spot").append("<tr><td>"+this['username']+":</td><td>"+this['comment']+"</td></tr>");  
        });
    }); 
}
```

below is the php file it works with, the problem am having is that it works fine when am not getting the variable i sent from the jquery

```
$result=array();
//$n=$_GET['n'];
$getJs=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM blog_comment");
while($rows=$getJs->fetch()){
    array_push($result, array(
        'username'=>$rows['username'],
        'comment'=>$rows['comment']
    ));
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

but when am getting the variable it does not work fine if i try to go directly to the php file i see this bunch of codes

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: n in C:\wamp\www\ezoole\js_backend\getComment.php on line <i>6</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0004</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>241728</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\ezoole\js_backend\getComment.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\getComment.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

please someone should help me resolve this.

Comment: $.postJSON is not standard jQuery but perhaps if you changed `{n:nid}` to `{"n::nid}` it might work, otherwise just use the standard jquery `post` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I think the problem is that you "post" your data but you use the superglobal `$_GET` in your PHP... you should use `$_POST` instead

Comment: +1 @Oliboy50 that sounds a much more sensible answer than mine!

Comment: i have tried your style and corrected the $_GET but still giving the same error

Answer (score 1):

The problen is that you are using `$n=$_GET['n'];` but the method you are using is post

Write

```
$n=$_POST['n'];
```

Instead of `$n=$_GET['n'];`

This should work correctly

```
$.ajax({
url:'../js_backend/getComment.php',
type:'POST',
data:{n:nid},
success: function(data){
$("#comment_view_spot").empty();    
    $.each(data.result, function(){
        $("#comment_view_spot").append("<tr><td>"+this['username']+":</td><td>"+this['comment']+"</td></tr>");
}
});
```

And on server side use

```
$n=$_POST['n'];
```

Comment: i have corrected it but  still giving me the same error